# How do I tell python to move to the next file in the directory?

Tags: python, elementtree

How do I move to the next file in Python after checking that the file extension is correct and parsing it in element tree? See code below. After the file is checked for .bpmn and parsed I would like to move to the next file and check if it is an .xml and then parse.

```
path = 'path_to_directory'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".bpmn"):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        tree = ET.parse(fullname)
        root = tree.getroot()

     else:
         print("must end with .bpmn")

    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        treeXML = ET.parse(fullname)
        rootXML = treeXML.getroot()
     else:
        print("must end with xml")
```

Comment: That is what loops are for. They will automatically move to the next item in the source iterable.

Answer (score 0):

for loops does it for you and continue bypass it.
The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning of the while loop. The continue statement rejects all the remaining statements in the current iteration of the loop and moves the control back to the top of the loop.

The continue statement can be used in both while and for loops.
for filename in os.listdir(path):

so filename keep changing after loop get executed.
try this.
   use continue
 path = 'path_to_directory'

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".bpmn"):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        tree = ET.parse(fullname)
        root = tree.getroot()
        continue
     else:
         print("must end with .bpmn")

    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        treeXML = ET.parse(fullname)
        rootXML = treeXML.getroot()
        continue
     else:
        print("must end with xml")
```

continue

```
import os, sys

# Open a file
path = "/var/www/html/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   print file
```